# Will the price of a bike go down if it doesnt have brakes?

Tags: brakes

Im selling my bike that is less than 2 years old from what the previous owner told me and I was gonna sell it for $300 (I paid $350) but I realized that it has no brakes (it came with the brakes disconnected). So I was wondering will I have to sell it cheaper or is that a decent amount or can i sell it for more?

Comment: Without knowing more information about the bike it's impossible to say what the bike is worth with or without brakes. Personally I wouldn't pay so much for a bike that isn't "ready to ride".  Then again, a frame, wheel, or bottle cage all by itself could be worth more than $300 if it is of sufficient quality.

Comment: There are places where selling a bike without two working brakes is illegal even if you're selling as an individual. There are sensible reasons for this to avoid selling to the unwary, so you need to make it very clear.

Comment: You should also keep in mind that unless it is specifically a track bike for only track use, many shops will not sell a bike without brakes.  A brakeless bike is inherently unsafe and a potential liability for the seller.

Comment: A bike without brakes is a parts donor, so its immediately worth far less than the same bike complete and working.

Answer (score 2):

First, look up what used bikes like yours sell for. You can use [Bicycleb Blue Book](http://www.bicyclebluebook.com/) or other sources. Also take a look on Craigslist and/or ebay. This will give you some idea of what a **working version of your bike is worth**.

Now figure out what it would cost to fix the brakes on your bike. Unless your bike is very special no one will want to buy it just for parts. Subtract the repair money from the price you found for similar bikes. Finally, take some extra money off the price (say $25 - $75) for inconveniencing your customer. Why should they buy from you and then have to fix the bike to ride it- they are better off buying a bike that doesn't need repair.